# installing pip autopep8 failed, invalid syntax?

Tags: python, pip, installation, autopep8

everyone.

I just started to learn python, and am currently trying to add some nice additional features to Atom.

I was trying to follow the steps from the video "Setting up a Python Development Environment in Atom": 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DjEuROpsvp4 (just for those who are interested to know more ,starting from around 13:30.)

But I failed at installing pip autopep8. As I downloaded "pip autopep8" in Atom and typed in "pip install autopep8" at the command line in python. what I got was a warning of "invalid syntax", which lead me to nowhere to know what got wrong.

[invalid syntax, installing pip autopep8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Iewb.png)

I hope someone could help me figure out what was the problem, and how could I push the installing forward. Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

Try in CMD:

```
pip install autopep8
```

Upon looking at your image, don't run pip through your IDLE, run it straight from CMD

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RH9cR.png  <-- Example

---

Editing because I found some additional info for future users.  If you're running additional versions of python on the same system (Centos for instance requires python 2 for a lot of dependencies) you can use the pip instance of a specific python install by running the following:

```
python3.6 -m pip install discord
```

As an example, python3.6 in my case was the additional instance I installed on my Centos server.  Normal pip was installing packages for the Python 2 instance.

Comment: Thanks! I know where I went wrong. I somehow thought this has something to do with python. So, I first run/entered ''python'' at CMD.

Comment: You've accessed the IDLE though.  Dont type in 'python' first.  Just open CMD and type in `pip install autopep8`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the screenshot you posted. I just run/entered "pip install autopep8" directly after I opened CMD, then the installation started!

Comment: Not a problem!  Glad it helped.